# Unity Autocomplete is not working with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Basically what the title says, I'm new to Unity and Visual Studio and I can't get Visual Code to autocomplete Unity's stuff.
I've tried almost every solution out there except for ones that were outdated.

I'm using:
Visual Studio Code 2022
Unity 2021.3.16f1

Tried almost all fixes on the internet but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Are you opening visual studio through the assets->load c# project or through some other method from the unity editor?

Comment: I'm opening it through Unity

Comment: You switch between Visual Studio, Visual Studio 2022, Visual Studio Code, Visual Code, and many others. I assume you are using visual studio 2022, visual studio code is an entirely different product. Have you installed the unity and c# extensions from visual studio installer?

Comment: I was indeed confusing Visual Studio Code with Visual Studio 2022. I deleted Visual Studio Code and I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2022 thorough the installer, but I keep getting this network error even tough my network is fine as you can see.
https://imgur.com/a/22pRwoe

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot view Imgur images from my current network. I don’t know what you mean by network errors, and I don’t know how this could be related. I might be able to help you in a few hours though.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A fresh Windows Installation did it for me!